# Convert audio files from various formats to mp3 and ogg

Tags: php, audio

I'm setting up a podcast. For cross-browser support, I currently need to upload a mp3 file and an ogg file. I'd like to simplify that process to uploading one of many audio files, that converts on the server into one mp3 and one ogg, then drops it into a folder. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose you need to use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) for the conversion and eventually [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/).

Like:

```
<?php
system ('ffmpeg -i /tmp/a.wav -ar 22050 /tmp/a.mp2', $retval); // took from the ffmpeg documentation. it's just an example
// add " > /dev/null &" if you want to execute in background
?>
```

Comment: @JacksonGariety You can't convert anything with ffmpeg-php, but you need to run ffmpeg (with PHP in your case).

Comment: im trying to solution. trying to run ffmpeg with php but i dont know how to do this?